# events.onOutOfBounds and events.onEnterBounds for phaser v3

Tags: game-physics, phaser-framework

In Phaser2.x we can get `events.onOutOfBounds and events.onEnterBounds` for a Sprite object by enabling `sprite.checkWorldBounds = true`, With this event i can track how long an image object appeared on the screen.

But in Pasher3.x, looks like it doesn't have events for `.onOutOfBounds and .onEnterBounds`

It 'd be great, if you can give some insights on tracking how long an image object appeared on the screen on Phaser3.x

Answer (score 0):

Please specify your question clearly. I'm guessing you are asking how to make a sprite bounce from boundaries in phaser3.

According to: https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game/part5

you can create sprite that bounces to walls by:

```
player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'dude');

player.setBounce(0.2);
player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
```

EDIT:
It seems like this feature (getting time when boundary is touched) is not implemented yet..(?)

https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/v3.11.0/src/physics/arcade/World.js#L57

Comment: His question is about tracking time of the sprite object which goes out and comes back of screen

Answer (score 0):

In Phaser 3 you can use....

```
update() {

    // wrap(object [, padding])
    this.physics.world.wrap(yourSprite, 48);

}
```

Resources:

1. https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/physics/arcade/wrap-sprite
2. https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.World.html